# <a>...</a> tag exceeds thumbnail width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I have a problem with my thumbnails, I add a TEXT tag in my thumbnail, and if the TEXT is too long, it cause the TEXT exceed the thumbnail width. EXPECTATION:

```
+----------------------------------+
| Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetu|
| er                               |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

REALITY:

```
       col-md-6
+----------------------------------+
| Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetuer
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

This is my code:

```
while()
{
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="thumbnail" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px">
       <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</a>
    </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: And where is your code...?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example : https://jsfiddle.net/ks3r78bu/

HTML :

```
<div class="img-cont">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.img-cont{
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
}
.img-cont p{
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  top:-150px;
  left:0px;
}
```